# C# LINQ query (MYSQL EF) - Distinct and Latest Records

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-4, distinct

I have a table, lets call it Record. Containing:
ID (int) |  CustID (int)  |  Time (datetime)  |  Data (varchar)

I need the latest (most recent) record for each customer:

**SQL**

```
select * from record as i group by i.custid having max(id);
```

**LINQ version 1**

```
dgvLatestDistinctRec.DataSource = from g in ee.Records
                                  group g by g.CustID into grp
                                  select grp.LastOrDefault();
```

This throws an error:

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code Message=LINQ
>   to Entities does not recognize the method 'Faizan_Kazi_Utils.Record
>   LastOrDefault[Record
>   ](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Faizan_Kazi_Utils.Record
>   ])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression. Source=System.Data.Entity

**LINQ version 2**

```
var list = (from g in ee.Records
            group g by g.CustID into grp
            select grp).ToList();
Record[] list2 = (from grp in list
                  select grp.LastOrDefault()).ToArray();
dgvLatestDistinctRec.DataSource = list2;
```

This works, but is inefficient because it loads ALL records from the database into memory and then extracts just the last (most recent member) of each group.

Is there any LINQ solution that approaches the efficiency and readability of the mentioned SQL solution?

Comment: How you achieved Mysql+LINQ. Is DBSet supporting Mysql. If so, can you please say how?. I was dying to achieve this, and gave up at last week.

Comment: I just need the core points , at least where you put that connection string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

```
var results = (from rec in Record group rec by rec.CustID into grp 
    select new
    {
        CustID = grp.Key,
        ID = grp.OrderByDescending(r => r.ID).Select(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault(),
        Data = grp.OrderByDescending(r => r.ID).Select(x => x.Data).FirstOrDefault()
    }
);
```

So I made a test table and wrote a Linq -> SQL Query that will do exactly what you need. Take a look at this and let me know what you think. Only thing to keep in mind if this query is scaled I believe it will run a query to the DB for each and every CustID record after the grouping in the select new. The only way to be sure would be to run SQL Tracer when you run the query for info on that go here .. http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/tuning-sql-server-for-programmers/

Original:

Could you do something like this? `from g in ee.Records where g.CustID == (from x in ee.Records where (g.CustID == x.CustID) && (g.ID == x.Max(ID)).Select(r => r.CustID))`

That's all pseudo code but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Ok, so I tried what you're talking about and its giving errors on the two wheres: Delegate System.Func<Faizan_Kazi_Utils.Record,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: and on ID in Max(ID) its giving: The name 'id' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I get what youre trying to do, but I've been unable to make the required changes to get it to work :s

Comment: I choose to OrderByDescending since Linq->SQL doesn't support the MAX() feature unless you force it to memory first. Side note try using Linqpad it makes this kind of stuff 10x easier.

Comment: ah... nice :) im going to test this out soon. I do use linqpad when i need to (been using it to test queries), except this time the theory and experience needed went a little above my head.. thus i posted the question here :)

Comment: Sweet!!! Glad I could help you out man that's crazy that your in Pakistan. Amazing now days that you can get help from thousands of miles away. Take care.

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably too late to help with your problem, but I had a similar issue and was able to get the desired results with a query like this:

```
from g in ee.Records
group g by g.CustID into grp
from last in (from custRec in grp where custRec.Id == grp.Max(cr => cr.Id) select custRec)
select last
```

Answer (score 1):

I think grp.LastOrDefault(), a C# function, is something that SQL doesn't know about. LINQ turns your query into an SQL query for your db server to understand. You might want to try and create an stored procedure instead, or another way to filter out what your looking for.

The reason your second query works is because the LINQ to SQL returns a list and then you do a LINQ query (to filter out what you need) on a C# list, which implements the IEnumerable/IQueryable interfaces and understands the grp.LastOrDefault().

Comment: True, LastOrDefault is not implemented in the MySQL Entity Framework provider (as the error shows).

Comment: Yup, it returns a long list as an in memory collection, which is then filtered down to single entries per CustID, which is not ideal in terms of memory & processor usage. And thats why I'm seeking help here :)

Answer (score 1):

What if you replace LastOrDefault() with simple Last()?
(Yes, you will have to check your records table isn't empty)

Because I can't see a way how MySQL can return you "Default" group. This is not the thing that  can be simply translated to SQL.

Comment: When I use Last I get this error: System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Faizan_Kazi_Utils.Record Last[Record](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Faizan_Kazi_Utils.Record])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
  Source=System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 0):

I had another idea:

```
// Get a list of all the id's i need by:
// grouping by CustID, and then selecting Max ID from each group.
var distinctLatest = (from x in ee.Records
                          group x by x.CustID into grp 
                          select grp.Max(g => g.id)).ToArray();

// List<Record> result = new List<Record>();

//now we can retrieve individual records using the ID's retrieved above
// foreach (int i in distinctLatest)
// {
//    var res = from g in ee.Records where g.id == i select g;
//    var arr = res.ToArray();
//    result.Add(res.First());
// }

// alternate version of foreach
dgvLatestDistinctRec.DataSource = from g in ee.Records
                                           join i in distinctLatest
                                           on g.id equals i
                                           select g;
```

Comment: this is kinda based on bigamils solution... it generated this stream of thought in my head

Comment: You really don't want to do .ToArray() or ToList() at this point because that will return all records and put them into memory. You want Linq -> SQL to do all the work. Basically it builds a dynamic expression tree and doesn't actually execute any SQL until you request a value. Key things that request a vall (ToList(), ToArray(), First(), Last() etc) sorry if i'm being redundant. Anyways updated my answer to do exactly what you need. Please upvote / mark me as the answer if it works for you! Hope this was helpful

Comment: hmmm... but the first .ToArray just loads a couple integers to memory (the distinct cust id's) and then the second one does exactly what i need (loading entire records: the latest records for each distinct customer)... isn't that ok?

Comment: oh and also note, that the second query (.ToArray) will only have ONE record being retrieved at a time since it's by primary key (id) so it shouldnt load more than 1 record at a time into memory